# python while loop if all conditions are equal then do another random choice from list

Tags: python

This is my python code:

```py
import secrets
from time import sleep

ids = [{'id': number} for number in range(1, 5+1)]

rand1 = secrets.choice(ids)
rand2 = secrets.choice(ids)
rand3 = secrets.choice(ids)

n = 0
while rand1['id'] == rand2['id'] == rand3['id']:
        n += 1
        print('Before')
        print(rand1['id'], rand2['id'], rand3['id'])
        sleep(1)
        rand1 = secrets.choice(ids)
        rand2 = secrets.choice(ids)
        rand3 = secrets.choice(ids)
        print('After')
        print(rand1['id'], rand2['id'], rand3['id'])
```

I'm going to reach this:

> do the while loop and choose a random id until none of the
> rand1['id'], rand2['id'] and rand3['id'] are equal.
>
> Even two of them are equal, then do another for loop.

Comment: Why did you define `ids = [{'id': number} for number in range(1, 5+1)]` at first place?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi to create a list. If you run, it creates a list called `ids`.

Comment: Do you want to create a list of dictionaries that contain different id values?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi yes, that's correct.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? I can't see a question being asked.

Comment: If you want to pick 3 unique elements from a list, the easy way is to shuffle the list (and there are several easy ways to do that) then pick the first 3, just like a deck of cards.

Comment: @MSH the question is how to have three different ids while no single id is equal to another one. I mean `secrets.choice()` should have three different and non-equal ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping is not the right way to do this.  Just shuffle and deal:

```
import random

nums = list(range(1,5+1))
random.shuffle(nums)
ids = [{'id': n} for n in nums[:3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to shuffling, you can use `random.sample`. Like shuffling, the time taken is determinate, and you are guaranteed to get three unique numbers.

```
>>> random.sample(range(1, 5+1), 3)
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: This solution is better because it will raise `ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative` but the `shuffle` method would do something unwanted...

Answer (score 1):

The condition you wrote tells whether all three values are equal, which is not what you mentioned in your explanation. You can check whether all values are unique or not. There are multiple ways to implement it, on way is to use sets :

```
import secrets
from time import sleep

ids = [{'id': number} for number in range(1, 5+1)]

rand1 = secrets.choice(ids)
rand2 = secrets.choice(ids)
rand3 = secrets.choice(ids)

n = 0
while len(set([rand1['id'],rand2['id'],rand3['id']]))!=3:
        n += 1
        print('Before')
        print(rand1['id'], rand2['id'], rand3['id'])
        sleep(1)
        rand1 = secrets.choice(ids)
        rand2 = secrets.choice(ids)
        rand3 = secrets.choice(ids)
        print('After')
        print(rand1['id'], rand2['id'], rand3['id'])
```

Although if you don't insist on using `secrets` you can do it by shuffling the list and selecting first 3 elements from it.